# How to extract emails from string which does not contain @?

Tags: python-3.x

Here are the strings:

> firstname dot secondname at domain dot com some text goes here.

> firstnamesecondnamedomaincom some text goes here.

> firstname(dot)secondname(at)domain(dot)com some text goes here.

> firstname[dot]secondname[at]domain[dot]com some text goes here.

How can I use python to extract emails from these patterns?

Edit:
here is my attempt:

```
import re
text = 'firstname.secondname at domain dot com'

re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+['at']+[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+['dot']+[a-z]+", text)
```

Edit2:
this code:

```
import re
text = ' firstname.secondname at domain dot com sfdsf'
set(re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+[\s'at'\s]+[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+[\s'dot'\s]+[a-z]+", text, re.I))
```

Gives this output:
{'firstname.secondname at domain dot com'}

But for this:

```
import re
text = 'lkjasd firstname.secondname at domain dot com sfdsf'
set(re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+[\s'at'\s]+[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+[\s'dot'\s]+[a-z]+", text, re.I))
```

It shows produced this: {'domain dot com', 'lkjasd firstname.secondname at'}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :D What have you tried so far - for example have you considered a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: Updated my attempt in the original post.

Comment: How about `email.replace('dot', '.').replace('at', '@')`? Then you have a regular email and maybe format the optional brackets

Comment: the second string has nothing that can be considered as delimeter? how do you expect to know if it should be `firstname.lastname` or `firstn.amelastname`? In addition, your example has `.` in it and also the word `dot`, but this isn't one of your example strings in the beggining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the second example is not possible without any additional info, but for the other use cases it should work:

```
def get_email(s):
    dot = '.'
    delimiter_dict = {' dot ': dot, '(dot)': dot, '[dot]': dot, ' at ': '@', '(at)': '@', '[at]': '@'}
    for d in delimiter_dict:
        if d in s:
            s = s.replace(d, delimiter_dict[d])

    return s.split('com ')[0] + 'com'
```

Comment: @ShirazAhmad you're welcome :). when you get a correct, working solution for **your** question, you should mark it by clicking on the V sign at the top left of the answer.
when you see a helpful question/answer in general, you should click on the **up** arrow at the top left, to mark that it was helpful.
**note:** you might need specific amount of reputation in order to make some actions like **upvote**

Comment: So nice of you. Thanks